# What does the symbol $\Delta$ stands for?

Tags: cross-product, differential-operators

While studying Landau-Lifshitz equation following term appears,

$-m \times (m \times \Delta m) = \Delta m + |\nabla m|^2 m$

In above equation m is a vector quantity. It will be great if someone can point out what the symbol $\Delta$ here stands for and how these two sides are equal.

Comment: @alekhine: I was just about to work on a fuller solution when I realized that the right-hand side does not really make sense.

Comment: This is called "Vector Laplacian". In orthonormal coordinates it is just the Laplacian applied termwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition,
$$
\Delta = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial x_{i}^{2}}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

It is the [Laplace Operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator#Definition), or the divergence-of-the-gradient operator (not as catchy, though).